# TableViewController is not showing up in simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, tableview

i've created a TableViewController and i've added in my Json data, but the TableView is not showing. My code is working and is not giving any errors, the debugger looks fine as well, but all I see is a white screen. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

public var meals = [Meal]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchJSON {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  meals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default , reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.text = meals[indexPath.row].strMeal.capitalized
    return cell
}


func fetchJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    
    let jsonUrlString =  "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        print("invalid url string lel")
        return
    }
    print("Select a meal to make today!")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let mealDetailResponse = try decoder.decode(MealDetailResponse.self, from: data)
            for meals in  mealDetailResponse.meals {
                print("The Meal is \(meals.self)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: Add `self.meals = mealDetailResponse.meals` and check

Comment: where am I  adding this?

Comment: After the line `let mealDetailResponse  = ....`

Comment: as this? let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let mealDetailResponse = try decoder.decode(MealDetailResponse.self, from: data)
 self.meals = mealDetailResponse.meals I am still not getting any of my table list meals

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that @RTXGamer solution's works.
Also I removed the dispatch from the loop as you want your tableview to be updated only once after all the data have been processed (even if in your case there is only 1 item in `mealDetailResponse`

```
    func fetchJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

        let jsonUrlString =  "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
            print("invalid url string lel")
            return
        }
        print("Select a meal to make today!")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let mealDetailResponse = try decoder.decode(MealDetailResponse.self, from: data)
                self.meals = mealDetailResponse.meals
                for meals in mealDetailResponse.meals {
                    print("The Meal is \(meals.self)")
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
            }catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Alternatively you can dispatch inside the completion block where you actually need the main thread.

```
fetchJSON {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: did you actually get a tableView Presented to you back? because I still have a blank white screen ..

Comment: I got the table view displayed with the list of meals using the code I wrote up there, did you link properly your `tableView` outlet to a table view in the storyboard (interface builder) ?
You can breakpoint:
- inside the `do...catch` to ensure you actually got answers from the server.
- inside the `fetchJSON` completion block before reloading the data.
If both are working you do definitely have a UI issue